# Prove Corr$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$= Corr$(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})^{\otimes n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product, quantum-information

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be two Hermitian basis of $m\times m$ matrices with complex entries. For example, when $m=2$, $\mathcal{A}$ can be $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$ where $X,Y,Z$ are [Pauli Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). **Here we set the first element $\mathcal{A}_0$ and $\mathcal{B}_0$ to be $I$**.

Let $\rho$ be a $m^2\times m^2$ density matrix (positive,tr($\rho)=1$), and define the correlation matrix of $(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ to be **Corr**$(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})_{i,j}=tr((\mathcal{A}_i\otimes B_j)\rho)$, $0\leq i,j\leq m^2-1$. "$\otimes$" here denotes the Kronecker product.

Define **Corr**$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})_{\sigma,\tau}=tr((\mathcal{A}_\sigma\otimes \mathcal{B}_\tau)\rho^{\otimes n})$, here $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two vectors with length $n$, $0\leq\sigma_i,\tau_i\leq m^2-1$. $\mathcal{A}_\sigma$=$\otimes_{i=0}^{n-1}$$\mathcal{A_{\sigma_i}}$ and define $\mathcal{B}_\tau$ similarly.  Also we can see $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as $m^2$-adic numbers. So **Corr**$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ is an $m^{2n}\times m^{2n}$ matrix.

Now how to prove **Corr**$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$= **Corr**$(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})^{\otimes n}$? It is hard to get the $(i,j)$ entry of both sides and then compare. By far I have no good ideas.

Supplementary:

1. $\mathcal{A}_i$ is the $i$th element of the basis $\mathcal{A}$
2. By saying $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as $m^2$-adic numbers, it means $\sigma=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} m^{2i}\sigma_i$ (also $\tau$), so **Corr**$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})_{\sigma,\tau}$ is the $(\sigma,\tau)$ entry of **Corr**$(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Just to clarify some notation: $\mathcal A_i$ is the $i$th element of the basis $\mathcal A$, is that correct? Also, what do you mean by "we can see $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as $m^2$-adic numbers"?

Comment: Also, please put a space after punctuation in the future. I've edited your question to make this change here

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have added in the last paragraph.

Comment: The $\sigma,\tau$ entry of the right-hand side, I would think, is really equal to 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}[[(A_{\sigma_0} \otimes B_{\sigma_0}) \otimes \cdots \otimes (A_{\sigma_{m^2-1}} \otimes B_{\sigma_{m^2-1}})]\rho^{\otimes n}],
$$
which doesn't coincide with their definition of $[\mathsf{Corr}(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})]_{\sigma,\tau}$. Something seems amiss; maybe this is a mistake in the paper. By the way, the above trace simplifies to
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n} \operatorname{Tr}[(A_{\sigma_i} \otimes B_{\tau_i})\rho].
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Could you show how you get the entry form of the RHS? Maybe I misunderstand the notation of $(A_\sigma\otimes B_\tau)$ in the paper, actually it should be the expression you  give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I note in my comment, I believe that something is wrong with the statement as it is presented. For instance, it could be that $\mathcal A_\sigma \otimes \mathcal B_{\tau}$ has a different definition, as you note. Here's the proof assuming that we define $\bigotimes_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mathcal{A}_{\sigma_i}\otimes B_{\tau_i})$.

As you note in your comment, we need to show that these matrices have matching entries. That is, for any $\sigma, \tau \in [m^2 - 1]_{\geq 0}^n$,
$$
\mathsf{Corr}(\rho^{\otimes n},\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})_{\sigma,\tau}= [\mathsf{Corr}(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})^{\otimes n}]_{\sigma,\tau}
$$
for any $\sigma,\tau \in [m^2]_{\geq 0}^n$. The left-hand side can be manipulated as follows:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}((\mathcal{A}_\sigma\otimes \mathcal{B}_\tau)\rho^{\otimes n}) &= 
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left[\bigotimes_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mathcal{A}_{\sigma_i}\otimes \mathcal B_{\tau_i})\right]\rho^{\otimes n}\right)
\\ & = \operatorname{Tr}\left(\bigotimes_{i=0}^{n-1}[(\mathcal{A}_{\sigma_i}\otimes \mathcal B_{\tau_i})\rho]\right)
\\ & = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{Tr}[(\mathcal A_{\sigma_i} \otimes \mathcal B_{\tau_i})\rho]
= 
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathsf{Corr}(\rho,\mathcal A, \mathcal B)_{\sigma_i,\tau_i}.
\end{align}

To see that this matches the right-hand side, we need only use the fact that for $m^2 \times m^2$ matrices $M_0,\dots,M_{n-1}$, we have
$$
\left[\bigotimes_{i=0}^{n-1} M_i\right]_{\sigma,\tau} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} [M_i]_{\sigma_i,\tau_i},
$$
So that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}((\mathcal{A}_\sigma\otimes \mathcal{B}_\tau)\rho^{\otimes n}) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \operatorname{Tr}[(\mathcal A_{\sigma_i} \otimes \mathcal B_{\tau_i})\rho] = [\mathsf{Corr}(\rho,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})^{\otimes n}]_{\sigma,\tau}.
$$